# Can compiz ring-switcher show high resolution icons for minimized windows?

Tags: compiz, icons, minimize

Compiz ring-switcher shows minimized windows' icons of very low quality (other than the current icon theme btw). Can I make it pick SVG icons from the current icon theme instead?

PS: This is also true for shift-switcher.

Comment: CCSM>Ring Switcher>2nd Tab fifth Option, guess that didn't do it for you?.

Comment: @Uri, no it didn't, that simply changes the mode to something else, but doesn't solve the problem here above. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cant change that because Compiz use the icons from application itself:

See what [maniac](http://forum.compiz.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=53) have said at [Compiz forum](http://forum.compiz.org/viewtopic.php?f=133&t=13881&p=84349&hilit=icons%20ring#p84349):

`The icons shown in the switcher are taken directly from the application itself. Run 'xprop' in a terminal, click on the window, watch out for _NET_WM_ICON and you'll see what I mean 
It's not enough to change the 'start menu' icon (...)`

Comment: Yes it uses the desktop file, but then I wonder why it doesn't take the scalables by default, rather than stretching a PNG. Synapse does it, so Compiz should be able to do that I guess. But that's not something for this site, it should be pointed out to the Compiz development team. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Benjamin. If I ever found a workaround I will let you know.

Comment: 6 years after this question, no single workaround is found yet...